# trying to publish from rospy and subscribe with rosjava

Tags: java, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to publish a message from rospy to a subscriber in rosjava. I am using ros hydro. I copy pasted the subscriber code from the tutorials into my rosjava folder and built it with catkin_make. I am getting errors related to adding the dependencies. I need to add them in the gradle file i think and i dont know how. can somebody help me with this? thanks
I searched all the old and the new tutorials. I am using the subscriber code found here:
http ://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#publishers-and-subscribers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104186/trying-to-publish-from-rospy-and-subscribe-with-rosjava/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2013-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dependencies go in the sub-project build.gradle files.

Dependencies for fellow sub-projects have the format (note you don't need any version specification):

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':fellow_sub_project_name')
}
```

Dependencies for artifacts (jars) that are outside your gradle super project (typically repo) have the format:

```
dependencies {
 compile 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:rosjava_test_msgs:[0.1,0.2)'
}
```

The uniquely qualified name here (org.ros.rosjava_messages) is the directory the artifact can be found. The name (rosjava_test_msgs) is the jar name. The [) brackets tell it to pick up the latest release in that range (e.g. 0.1.6).

Artifacts can usually be found either in /opt/ros/hydro/share/maven or at https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0